# Performance of operations on partial columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operation

I am doing this operation on a Dataframe and I wonder if there is a more efficientt way to do it. I only want to apply it on part of the column so I can't use .assign(). I also can't use something like  data.loc['avgGain'] > 8 because I need the "i" to select between (i + 8) and (i + 7).

```
for i in range(len(data["avgGain"][8:])):

 data.loc[(i + 8), 'avgGain'] = (data.loc[(i + 7), 'avgGain'] * 6 + data.loc[(i + 8), 'gain']) / 7
```